# Facebook Adobe Flash Warning

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-apps

Our Facebook application is not using Adobe Flash at all, it was written in C# as an ASP.NET product. However, we keep seeing a warning on our Facebook application that we have to switch to HTML5 because Adobe Flash is dying out.
Our website is not using Adobe Flash at all, however we do use the Facebook Javascript SDK.
Why could this be happening? Simply a bug or the app uses Adobe Flash even though we're not aware of it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your app (probably a game) dashboard and in settings->basic->Facebook Web Games set Redirect to App/Page to no.

[image]